# Why am I getting a compiler warning for this if condition?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
if(nowPlayingIndex-1 >= 0){ }
```

I am using this condition in a function and I am getting the following compiler warning in xCode:

> Comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true.

How can this be true? If the value of `nowPlayingIndex` is `<= 0` then the above condition is false.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the type of nowPlayingIndex, if it is unsigned int then it is always true.

Comment: How can anyone possibly explain this better than the compiler warning you're getting?

Comment: This is one of the reasons you should always pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: C++ or Objective-C?  Make up your mind.

Comment: Oh of course its an unsigned int. Silly me... :) Thanks guys. Im not having a very good day today.

Comment: @BlueRaja does it really matter? An if condition statement is the same in both languages. I put C++ and Objective-c as tags just to give the post more visibility.

Comment: Much more clear (and works) if written this way: if(nowPlayingIndex >= 1){ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nowPlayinfIndex seems to be unsigned.  This means it's always positive.  If you go negative, you'll have a buffer overflow (underflow?)

Looking at how these things work in binary...Take an 8-bit signed integer for example:

```
10000000 (-127)
10000001 (-126)
```

with unsigned:

```
10000000 (127)
10000001 (128)
```

EDIT: Fixed the numbers

The left most bit, or the sign bit determines if your number is + or -.  When it's 1, you can consider it to be -127, so when you add it to your running total, you get a negative number.  However, with an 8-bit UNSIGNED integer, the sign bit has a value of +127.  This is also why signed integers cannot store as large + numbers as unsigned.

Comment: Normally "buffer overflow" means that you're literally overflowing a buffer and accidentally writing to memory outside of it. This is a different thing. "Integer overflow" is a better term. The binary representations here are also incorrect (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).
These points are not necessary for understanding the original issue.

Comment: Whoops. my bad. Kind of did it off the top of my head.  Thanks for noticing that. Anyhow, I figured it was good to see what's going on inside of the calculations to see exactly WHY things like this are the way they are.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure the type of `nowPlayingIndex` is *unsigned* integral type. If so, then `nowPlayingIndex -1` will be *unsigned* integral type also, which can never be negative, hence `nowPlayingIndex -1`  is always greater than or equal to `0`.

Therefore, you should write :

```
if ( nowPlayingIndex  >= 1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

`nowPlayingIndex` is apparently unsigned, so `nowPlayingIndex-1` can never be negative. Therefore the condition is always true, as the compiler is warning you.

Answer (score 0):

If `nowplayingindex` is unsigned, it cannot be `< 0`. And if I subtract 1, unsignedness wins and I get the maximum value possible for this datatype, still being a positive number.

You must work with signed values or cast to such one.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what is the datatype of `nowPlayingIndex` see my comment.
If it is `unsigned int` then that is your problem.

Just for fun, try to subtract 1 from an unsigned integer that is initilized with the value 0.
Check your result.

Answer (score 0):

That is a  bit weird, but try the following and see if it helps.

```
if ((nowPlayingIndex - 1) >= 0)
{
    //logic
}
```

Comment: Did you read the warning the OP has posted? It has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: It won't make a difference. `-` has higher precedence than `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the earlier correct answers, if `nowPlayingIndex == 0`, then `nowPlayingIndex - 1` is the maximum value of its type, e.g., UINT_MAX, which might be 4294967295.

You probably want to write:

```
if (nowPlayingIndex > 0) { ... }
```

or

```
if (nowPlayingIndex >= 1 { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

if nowPlayingIndex is unsigned char

```
unsigned char nowPlayingIndex = 0;
nowPlayingIndex = nowPlayingIndex - 1; // 255 (UCHAR_MAX in limits.h)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says on the tin. nowPlayingIndex is unsigned, nowPlayingIndex - 1 is unsigned as well, and all unsigned values are >= 0.

Try to use signed values instead. Ever since I rewrote all of my stuff to use signed values (my own int32 more precisely), everything is simpler and correctness is easier to ensure.

If that is too much effort, or not possible, simply use nowPlayingIndex >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, `0 - 1` can be greater than 0. I will show you:

```
$ cat foo.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int foo = 0;
    ::std::cout << (foo - 1) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -O3 foo.cpp -o foo

$ ./foo
4294967295
```

There you go.

Comment: And who gave you permission to use my name in your example? ;v)

Comment: *laugh* I guess I should change it to `foo`. I tend to use `fred`, `barney`, `wilma`, `betty` and `george` as metasyntactic variables.

Comment: Yeah, so does Marshall Cline.

Answer (score 0):

The variable nowPlayingIndex is probably an *unsigned integer*, representing a **positive number**, it is always >= 0.